# How to hook on event that is changing the html element but not the id with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a `div` with `id` lveventplayer. At some point a video streaming is fired from another script that I can't track and the `div` element is replaced with `iframe`. The `id` is still the same.

My question is: can I fire a function additional on/when the div is changed with the iframe?

Comment: Can you give us your code so we have something to go ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a *DOMNodeInserted* event is what you are looking for because the div actually gets replaced with a different element and this new element has to be insered into the DOM so a *DOMNodeInserted* event is called.

```
// simulate video streaming event that triggers a div-element to be replaced with a different iframe-element
setTimeout(function(){
  var testDiv = $('#testDiv');
  var testIframe = $('<iframe id="testDiv"></iframe>');
  testDiv.replaceWith(testIframe);
},3000);

// ACTUAL CODE
// check for new elements that are going to be inserted
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted',function(){
  // this anonymous function is called as soon as a new DOM-element is inserted,
  // therefore you have to check whether a new inserted element is your iframe-element
  var testIframe = $('#testDiv');
  if(testIframe.length){
    alert('iframe: '+testIframe.attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated and Mutation observers is recommended. So far I found this : https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/ as very useful explanation of how to work with mutation observer and as well - the source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure? Jquery does not list on within its deprecated [list](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/). the method on is a successor of live and it more likely to work on older versions of IE than 11.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, you can use the find method  to find that particular div and do the logic.

Example: $('#your div which is not dynamic').find('#id of the player').